# Use the Mediawiki SpecialPage class on a different namespace

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'd like to use the Mediawiki SpecialPage class on a page in my customized "Data:" namespace.

The MediaWiki [Manual on Special Pages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Special_pages#General_Information) states:

> The general form is "Special:Pagename" where both "Special" and
>   "Pagename" are customizable. The Special pseudo namespace can be
>   translated in other languages. This translated namespace can be
>   produced with the wikitext {{ns:special}}, on this wiki giving
>   "Special". The name of the special page can also be redefined in a
>   system message, for the site language, with the generic name of the
>   special page as the ID.

This reads to me like the "Special" namespace is only customizable to accommodate use in other languages.  In other words, the Special namespace itself will change rather than choosing a different namespace for a specific page.

Is that correct, or is there a way I can in fact include the SpecialPage class in another namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `SpecialPage` is for its particular namespace. To combine content with UI, look towards the `Content` / `ContentHandler` combination.